# GPS location trigger for Arcore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am completely fresh in coding and Unity/ArCore. I am looking to get into it and would love some pointers on where I can get started to learn how this software works?

One app I am interested in making this:

- Device enters GPS location that triggers 3D scene/animation
- Scene is triggered at different but specific GPS location (a bit further out)

Is this possible with current tech? Would appreciate any help to get me to this level of skill.